# Cos'è "l'acqua di scolo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Nei giorni piú piovigginosi di settembre, quando il cielo diventa una fuliggine e **l’acqua di scolo**, mescolandosi con l’acqua piovana, trasforma i cortili in piscine, Diamante si ritrova a camminare per le vie inzaccherate di fango senza il fascio di giornali sottobraccio.

Ho cercato il termine "scolo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cos'è "l'acqua di scolo". L'acqua che scola dai tetti a causa di queste piogge di cui parla il brano? (ma se è questo il caso non capisco perché si afferma che si mescola con l'acqua piovana) Le acque residuali?

Comment: Sembrerebbe l’acqua proveniente dalle grondaie che esce dagli scarichi al suolo e si mescola con l’acqua dal cielo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

il commento è corretto.

Piovendo, l'acqua prende due percorsi: in parte va direttamente a terra ("acqua piovana"), in parte viene raccolta dalle grondaie ed incanalata a terra ("acqua di scolo").

Scolo nel senso dell'atto di [uscire lentamente](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=scolare%203).
Si vede bene [qui](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scolo.shtml) (dove si intravede l'altro uso, a me familiare, di chiamare "scolo" quel rigolo d'acqua che talvolta si forma a bordo strada, prima di entrare in un tombino).